# Why do I get a TypeError in this Python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, zipf

```
# I'm trying to make a Zipf's Law observation using a dictionary that stores every word, and a counter for it. I will later sort this from ascending to descending to prove Zipf's Law in a particular text. I'm taking most of this code from Automate the Boring Stuff with Python, where the same action is performed, but using letters instead.
message = 'the of'
words = message.split()
wordsRanking = {}
for i in words:
    wordsRanking.setdefault(words[i], 0)
    wordsRanking[i] += 1   
print(wordsRanking)
```

This code gives me the following error:
**TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**
How do I resolve this? I would be really grateful.

Comment: Because i is a word, not an index; Python for loops iterate over the elements.

Comment: Many questions already answered can help you. Just type your error message in search bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we debug:

```
message = 'the of'
words = message.split()
wordsRanking = {}
for i in words:
    print(i) ### add this
    wordsRanking.setdefault(words[i], 0)
    wordsRanking[i] += 1   
print(wordsRanking)
```

The output is that:

```
the ## this is what printed. and word[i] is now equal to word["the"]. that raise an error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\Desktop\start\try.py", line 6, in <module>
    wordsRanking.setdefault(words[i], 0)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

As you can see iterating `words` by for loop gives us elements of `word`. Not an integer or index of element. So you should use `wordsRanking.setdefault(i, 0)`:

```
message = 'the of'
words = message.split()
wordsRanking = {}
for i in words:
    wordsRanking.setdefault(i, 0)
    wordsRanking[i] += 1   
print(wordsRanking)
```